# Operation similar to Python's "if x in y" for C/C++?

Tags: c++, python, c

I have known Python for a while, trying to get my head around C.

I was wondering if there was anything similar to Python's

```
if x in y:
```

for example if `x` is `2` and `y` is `2540` the statement would be true, as `y` contains `x` as a digit.

Is there anything similar to this for C/C++? Because I haven't found it yet if there is.

Comment: `x` and `y` are strings?

Comment: Strings , or ints. I know for sure it works with those two types.

Comment: In my particular dilemma for C, they are ints :)

Comment: "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable", so this does not work for ints.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, if `y` is a `std::string` or a standard collection, you could use e.g. [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (or the collections own `find` method) to see if it's in the collection.

---

In C, if `y` is a string, you could use [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to see if a character is in the string.

---

For integers, there is no such method. You could convert the number to a string (using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++, or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) in C) and then use one of the methods mentioned above.

Comment: As Joachim Pileborg said, for C++ strings or containers, use "std::find", and for C strings use the standard library function "strchr()".  For integers, the question `is there a '2' in '2540'?` *MAKES NO SENSE*.  The integer "2540" *is* "2540"; it does *not* "have a 2" ... unless you consider it as a *decimal string".  Which takes you right back to "find" and "strchr()".  IMHO...

Answer (score 3):

**I wouldn't convert the numbers to strings for this particular problem**

simply because it is not necessary. Instead, look at this function (C code):

```
#include <assert.h>

int is_digit_in_number(unsigned char digit, unsigned int number)
{
    assert(digit < 10);
    while(number)
    {
        if(number % 10 == digit)
            return 1;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this saves you the overhead of converting the number to string, and gives the compiler some room for smart optimizations. Also, imo it's clearer for the reader what the code **should** do, which is always a good thing :)

Cheers,
Andy